# How do I get nvidia drivers to work on Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: boot, 14.04, xubuntu

I installed and tested multiple Nvidia drivers such as 331 and 304 but every time I always end with Xubuntu on a black screen after the booting screen. How do I make them work successfully on my 2010 15 inch macbook pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with installing the accelerated graphics driver for Nvidia, the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
```

Comment: Well Noveau (thats the default driver right?) works just fine, but I would like to use the nvidia drives, especially because the boot screen looks better.

Comment: Try with `nvidia-common`

Comment: I think the nvidia common worked for me, so if you add it to your answer, I can mark it as correct.